# How can I move the keyboard focus to the view after ReactiveUI routing

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

Hello I'm using ReactiveUI for my Wpf application and I run into a problem. My mainscreen uses a RouterViewHost to display the view that is currently active.

After my mainscreen routes to a new view the keyboard focus moves to the Mainform and I would like to have it moved to the first focusable control inside the view that is currently displayed in the RoutedViewHost.

What is the best way to achieve this. I found that the following code works, but is that the best/desired way to do this?

```
        RoutedViewHost.TransitionCompleted += (s, e) => RoutedViewHost.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

Thanks Niek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use the built in routing, but could you use `this.WhenActivated` in the view's code behind?

```
public partial class FooView : UserControl, IViewFor<FooViewModel>
{
    public FooView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            SomeTextField.Focus();
        });
    }

    public FooViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (FooViewModel) GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(FooViewModel), typeof(FooView), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (FooViewModel) value; }
    }
}
```